# Is there automatic topology discovery support in Redisson Redis client?

Tags: redis, redisson

The [documentation](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration) suggests that we create a redisson instance with a specific Redis configuration (clustered, replicated, master-slave etc).

```
config.useClusterServers() // or
config.useReplicatedServers()
```

In situations where I only have the endpoint of one of the nodes in the cluster, will Redisson discover the deployment mode of the cluster (replicated, sharded etc) without the user having to instantiate with a specific configuration. If it does, then which of the available configuration would be ideal to start of with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In situations where I only have the endpoint of one of the nodes in the cluster, will Redisson discover the deployment mode of the cluster (replicated, sharded etc) without the user having to instantiate with a specific configuration.

You should use Cluster configuration for cluster environment or cloud like (AWS, Azure). In this case it's required only one endpoint node to specify.

Replicated configuration used only for single master environment and/or multiple slaves on cloud (AWS, Azure) or any other deployment

Comment: In addition to the answer by @Nikita, DNS is also monitored for changes in Sentinel, Master/Slave and Replicated mode.